# Multiple customer dimension

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I am new to dwh and creating data warehouse for my company. We have a customer dimensions which we want to create.However finance team customer list Id and name are different from the CRM list ID and name.
We created a mapping table but sometimes for same finance ID we have multiple crmid How should I handle this...do I have to create two customer dimension

```
   CRM        Name
  CRMID1     XXXX
  CRMID2     YYYYY
  CRMID3     ZZZ
```

Mapping table

```
   CRMID    FINID
   CRMID1   FINID1
   CRMID2   FINID1
   CRMID3   FINID2
   CRMID4   FINID3
```

FinTable

```
   FINID1   XXXX
   FINID2   YYYY
   FINID3   ZZZ
```

When I create the Dimension and join these three tables

Final Dimension

```
  ClientKey CRMID   FINID
    1      CRMID1   FINID1
    2      CRMID2   FINID1
    3      CRMID3   FINID2
    4      CRMID4   FINID3
```

This causes duplication when I join the dimension table with Fact table and  add the ClientKey in the Fact table.

Should I create Two Dimension  for Client or Is their any other way I can handle it in one dimension.

Comment: an example of the data that demonstrates the problem would be very helpful. A solution depends on what these multiple Ids mean - do they have a real business meaning, or are they just a symptom of bad data quality?

Comment: Bad data quality.In CRM we have ID and Name however in Finance sometimes we have same CustID linked to multiple CRMID. But the team does not want change anything in terms of data.

Comment: Please help with this issue

Comment: Sorry but your example makes no sense... It shows that your map is screwed up while data itself is perfectly fine.

Comment: Mapping table is created by finance team..And thats where the problem is coming.The CRM system came recently and during migration from old sales system to new CRM they have missed lot of CustomerID.I spoke to Finance people and they said that's the best mapping table we can create.

Comment: Well, in that case there is no solution other than to create a different map. Their map is just plain wrong (assuming you described it correctly).

Comment: yah..but finance team has declined to change it.They are asking to create two Customer dimension.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Every company must have one master customer set - the single source of truth. DW projects should NOT be driven by Finance department. It must be a company-wide effort with strong political support.  If you don't have it, your project has high chances of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Data Warehouse you ***must*** have a unique customer ID.

A solution involving your operational systems is **best** (i.e - Master Data Management) but if this is too hard to drive (and it usually is) at least create a unique customer ID in the DWH Customer dimension.

Both the CRMID and the FINID are attributes of a customer in the Customer dimension regardless of the current relation between them (1:1 or 1:M or even M:M).

As [mmarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514839/mmarie) mentioned your unique customer ID ***can*** be a combination of business keys but I ***strongly*** advise creating a separate surrogate key since as [Ralph Kimball](https://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/surrogate-keys/) states production keys are unstable\volatile.

Another reason is that your source systems change over time (like you mentioned) even when your customers don’t so you need the ability to track and report on a customer over multiple systems and periods.

Assuming you will go for a SCD type 2 – you will want something like this:

- PK (Surrogate, time variant)
- CustomerID (Surrogate, permanent, DWH generated, unique per customer)
- CRMID (CRM business key)
- FINID (business key)
- ATTRIBUTE_1
- ATTRIBUTE_2
- START_DATE
- END_DATE

Comment: @eExpialidoshes    The Problem I am facing in creating one Customer Dimension is ..Some of the Clients whose project  we currently have  open / lost deals are only present in CRM table but not present in Finance table as they are not our real customer  with whom we get revenue.     Also , finance system we have is from 2014 but the CRM system we  recently purchased .They did not migrated all data from the old CRM system into new one .So we have some old projects whose customer  information is  not present in CRM system  but are present in Finance .

Comment: My reply was too long so i had to open a new answer .. se below

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping is always 1:1 or M:1 CRM Customer:Finance Customer, then you shouldn't have to create two customer dimensions. But everyone involved will have to understand that there are multiple levels/views of customers and that this can complicate things. It is a somewhat common situation to have a difference between the marketing customer/purchase decision customer and the billing customer. These customer attributes are combined in master data management and data warehouses for a coherent combined view called a conformed dimension.

In the reporting system/data mart, you just need to define your mapping table and ultimately your single customer dimension at the level of granularity of the CRM customer ID. Just treat the FINID as a nonunique attribute of the customer

You may end up having to identify a "parent customer" so that facts at the granularity of the financial system don't duplicate data across all CRMIDs with matching FINIDs. If you can flag the parent customer (One CRMID per FinID), then you can attribute all financial facts to that parent customer CRMID and all marketing/sales facts to any applicable CRMID.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem mapping all described relations in a central DIM_CUSTOMERS, see 2 last records in the below sample

1. CRMID    FINID
2. CRMID1   FINID1
3. CRMID2   FINID1
4. CRMID3   FINID2
5. **CRMID4   -1**
6. **-1        FINID2**

It seems to me your problem is more with **driving cooperation between different parts of the company** and its quite a common challenge in DWH projects

The DWH key job is to integrate separate silos of the organization and it takes time for different departments to understand how they affect each other.

The best way to encourage\push your finance team & CRM owner to sync data between them (after giving them a heads up regarding the problem) is simply to **report\reflecting garbage data** (customers not existing in the new CRM or not mapped by finance).

This will either

1. Put management pressure on both players to sync entities – In which case you only need to update the -1 keys in your dimension, or
2. Reflect the problem is not as important as you fill – in which case your work is done